# Delete all after @ sign with Notepad?

Tags: notepad++

> 530710189@cmu.ac.th:Yui159879@wx4400.cmu/aaa/CMU.html
>   ka_toon_27@reed.co:054772149@www.hi5.com/friend/displayHomePage.do

how way with regex to do this one:

> 530710189@cmu.ac.th:Yui159879
>
> ka_toon_27@reed.co:054772149

and delete this?

> @wx4400.cmu/aaa/CMU.html
>
> @www.hi5.com/friend/displayHomePage.do

Comment: An upvote in a post showing no-effort??? What have you tried little python?

Comment: (.*?)@(.*?)(.*) repalce with
$1$2

Comment: I'd suggest you to update your post with that information, it will attract human beings of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Find-Replace window:

```
Find what: (@[^@]*)@.*
Replace with: $1
```

And make sure the `Regular expression` radio button is marked.

How it works:

It captures the `@` character followed by anything but `@` and by another `@` to the end of the string and overwrites with just the beginning of the match (which is basically everything up to the second `@` character).

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't what you looking for, but a very crude work around would be:

- Find and replace '@' with ',' and save it as a .csv file.
- Open it with excel or something similar and delete the coloumn you don't want (in this case the third one) and save it.
- Open it back up with NotePad++ and find and replace ',' with '@' and save it with a new extension (i.e. txt).

Edit: Looked up some stuff on regex and you can do this,

Find what: (.+)\s*@\s*(.+)@\s*(.+)

Replace with: $1@$2

and have the 'Regular expression' box ticked.